# How to check if a web service is running in multiple threads instead of a single one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, singleton, asmx

I have a webservice (asmx) that is running on 2 different servers that sit behind a load balancer. The service is called by multiple clients across our organization, as per my current knowledge, none of the clients use multiple threads.

I'm investigating a production issue where some of the data in a few static variables is clearing or returning null or empty, causing db exceptions and foreign key constraint errors.

Upon investigation, I noticed that the singleton pattern is not implemented correctly, so it's definitely not multi thread safe.

I checked with my team and see if there is any scenario where the service might run under multiple threads but they're all saying no.

I don't know why but I'm still convinced that it is running multiple threads as all the production issues I see align with the multi thread functionality. I can also force these errors when I do a parallel.invoke in my unit test cases, but I cannot find the scenario where it's happening on a day to day basis.

I was wondering if there is any way to go through the IIS logs or anything on the windows servers itself that might clarify this situation whether the service or anything inside it is using multiple threads while it's running.

Is it possible that on each IIS, the service is in its own single thread but when it calls other classes and methods within itself, they start their own thread?

I apologize for not sharing any code yet, just given the sheer amount of code, I didn't get a chance to extract part of it to post it here, I'll need to refactor quite a few things before I can post it here.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you've decided that it's a threading issue and that's where you're focused, when the actual problem is the static vars not being populated.  Focus on that, debug it from the beginning, and don't guess until you have a reason to.  Also, load balancing sounds a culprit here.  Maybe moving data into a database would be sensible.

Comment: AFAIK **every** external request is handled in a separate thread. 10 clients submitting a request at the same time will cause 10 threads on the server processing that requests

Comment: @Archer I see your point but the only reason I was driven to the multi-thread issue was because I was able to replicate this exact scenario when I ran my test program in multithreads (Parallel.Invoke). I'm not discarding other options, this is just one of the items that needs investigation

Comment: You might want to consider not using mutable static variables.

Comment: ASMX web services run under ASP.NET and are bound by all of its rules and properties. Check the settings of the Application Pool(s) for concurrency and restart intervals. The IIS log files won't tell you much, unfortunately. If you have access to the servers then the ASP.NET counters in Performance Monitor might help you to figure out when things are happening. BE AWARE: even though your service may be configured for single threading (maxWorkerThreads=1) that only applies within a single w3wp.exe process and IIS can start multiple w3wp.exe processes within a given Application Pool! Good luck!

Comment: Also on the Application Pools front, a lot of the system.web/httpRuntime settings (such as maxWorkerThreads) have no effect if the pool is running in Integrated mode instead of Classic mode, REF: [ASP.NET threading settings are not used to control the request concurrency in Integrated mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis#23-aspnet-threading-settings-are-not-used-to-control-the-request-concurrency-in-integrated-mode)

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning. I checked the app pools on both servers and the mxWorkerThreads is set to 1, so that rules that out. Based on your last comment, if AppPool starts another w3wp.exe process, are there any chances of it interfering with another thread launched by the same app pool running under the same ID?

Comment: @hsandhar It won't affect static variables (because each running process keeps its own copy of those) but if you have any other shared data, such as MemoryMappedFiles, any mutex/lock guards you have around those will fall apart when there are multiple w3wp.exe processes running within the same pool.